# Kinematics of 2-body decays

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics

> Consider a 2-body decay $M\to X+Y$. **I am looking for the
> distribution function of a particle $X$ by having the distribution of
> a particle $M$.**

To proceed, I start from the following equation:
$$
(p_{M}-p_{X})^{2} = p_{Y}^{2} = m_{Y}^{2},
$$
or
$$
E_{X}^{\text{M rest}} - \frac{E_{M}E_{X}-|\mathbf{p}_{M}||\mathbf p_{X}|\cos(\alpha)}{m_{M}} = 0,
\tag 1
$$
where $E_{X}^{\text{M rest}} = \frac{m_{M}^{2}+m_{X}^{2}-m_{Y}^{2}}{2m_{M}}$ is the energy of the particle $X$ at the $M$'s rest frame, and
$$
\cos(\alpha) = \cos(\theta_{M})\cos(\theta_{X})+\sin(\theta_{M})\sin(\theta_{X})\cos(\phi_{M}-\phi_{X})
$$
is the angle between $\mathbf{p}_{M}$ and $\mathbf{p}_{X}$.

> **Suppose that we fix $E_{X}$ and $\theta_{X}$. Then Eq. $(1)$ gives us allowed values of $E_{M}$, $\theta_{M}$ and $\Delta\phi$.**

Solving Eq. (1) with respect to $E_{M}$, for energies $E_{X}>E_{X}^{\text{M rest}}$  and angles
$$
|\cos(\alpha)| > \cos(\alpha_{\text{crit}}), \quad \text{where} \quad \cos(\alpha_{\text{crit}}) = \frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{(E_{X}^{\text{M rest}})^{2}}{E_{X}^{2}}}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{m_{X}^{2}}{m_{M}^{2}}}}
\tag 2
$$
we have two solutions:
$$
E_{M}^{\pm} = \frac{E_{X}m_{M}E_{X,\text{rest}}\pm \sqrt{4E_{X}^{2}m_{M}^{2}E_{X,\text{rest}}^{2}-(E_{X}^{2}-p_{X}^{2}\cos^{2}\alpha)\big[m_{M}^{2}p_{X}^{2}\cos^{2}\alpha +E_{X,\text{rest}}^{2}m_{M}^{2}\big]}}{(E_{X}^{2}-p_{X}^{2}\cos^{2}\alpha)},
$$
See the behavior of these solutions as a function of $\cos(\alpha)$ for particular values of $E_{X}, m_{X},m_{Y},m_{M}$ below:
[image]

> **My questions are the following.**

1. What is the physical meaning of the existence of two solutions $E_{M}^{\pm}$?
2. In $(2)$, how should I interpret the modulus, and does the sign of the modulus depend on the choice $E_{M}^{+}/E_{M}^{-}$? Naively, I should use only the positive sign, i.e. $\cos(\alpha)>\cos(\alpha_{\text{crit}})$, which means that $X$ flies in the narrow cone around the momentum $\mathbf{p}_{M}$. But maybe for the larger solution $E_{M}^{+}$ the angle should be negative (i.e., a very energetic particle $M$ emits $X$ with $E_{X}\ll E_{M}$ backward)? But I don't see how does the relationship between the modulus and $E_{M}^{\pm}$ follow from $(1)$, $(2)$.